Python-escpos | No obtengo conexión entre POS y vstudioCode
dado el siguiente código
from escpos.printer import Serial, Usb

""" Seiko Epson Corp. Receipt Printer (EPSON TM-T88III) """
VID = 0x04b8  # ID de vendedor
PID = 0x0e15  # ID de product


#p = Usb(0x04b8, 0x0E15, 0, profile="TM-T20II")
p = Serial(devfile='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1.00, dsrdtr=True)
p.text("Hello World\n")
p.cut() 

Me tira el siguiente error en la terminal de VisualStudioCode (code runner extension):
PS C:\Users\LucioHong> & C:/Users/LucioHong/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.exe "c:/Users/LucioHong/Downloads/Hello World EscPos2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\printer\serial.py", line 136, in open
    self.device: Optional[serial.Serial] = serial.Serial(
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        port=self.devfile,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...<6 lines>...
        dsrdtr=self.dsrdtr,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
    ^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
    ~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 80, in open
    self._reconfigure_port()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
    raise SerialException(
        'Cannot configure port, something went wrong. '
        'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona.', None, 31)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LucioHong\Downloads\Hello World EscPos2.py", line 10, in <module>
    p.text("Hello World\n")
    ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\escpos.py", line 853, in text
    self.magic.write(txt)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\magicencode.py", line 282, in write
    self.write_with_encoding(encoding, to_write)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\magicencode.py", line 306, in write_with_encoding
    self.driver._raw(
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        CODEPAGE_CHANGE + six.int2byte(self.encoder.get_sequence(encoding))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
    ^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\printer\serial.py", line 164, in _raw
    self.device.write(msg)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\escpos.py", line 145, in device
    self.open()
    ~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\printer\serial.py", line 50, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LucioHong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\escpos\printer\serial.py", line 150, in open
    raise DeviceNotFoundError(
        f"Unable to open serial printer on {self.devfile}:\n{e}"
    )
escpos.exceptions.DeviceNotFoundError: Device not found (Unable to open serial printer on COM4:
Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona.', None, 31))

Lo probé por ambos, sea USB o Serial porque no sabia muy bien cual tipo de conexión es: Es una pos Epson TM-T20II, la cual conecto por USB, pero me figura "COM4" en administrador de dispositivos. Por ello lo intenté hacer por USB o Serial, de todas maneras ninguna de las dos opciones funcionan.Por usb, me cercioré de que los IDs vendors y product fueran los correctos.
Puerto: COM4

Descripción: TM-T20II (COM4)

ID del hardware: USB VID:PID=04B8:0E15 SER=544336460659530000 LOCATION=1-1

Vendedor: 1208

Producto: 3605

Uso: None

------------------------------

Por serial, estoy seguro de todos los datos indicados, baudrate, bytesie, etc.
No estoy entendiendo porque el código no está encontrando la impresora, si es que desde mi pc (windows) pude realizar la prueba de impresión instalando el driver.
Cabe destacar,
Puse la impresora en modo de uso compartido
estas son las dependencias descargadas:
C:\Users\LucioHong>pip list

Package             Version

------------------- ------------

appdirs             1.4.4

argcomplete         3.5.1

colorama            0.4.6

docutils            0.21.2

future              1.0.0

importlib_metadata  8.5.0

importlib_resources 6.4.5

libusb              1.0.27.post3

libusb1             3.1.0

packaging           24.1

pillow              10.4.0

pip                 24.2

pkg-about           1.2.1

pyserial            3.5

python-barcode      0.15.1

python-escpos       3.0

pyusb               1.2.1

pywin32             307

PyYAML              6.0.2

qrcode              8.0

setuptools          75.1.0

six                 1.16.0

viivakoodi          0.8.0

zipp                3.20.2

